# Как вычислить разницу дат на Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать функцию на Swift, возвращающую разницу в днях между двумя датами.

```
func dateDiff (pastDate: Date, nowDate: Date) -> Int {

    ...

    return ...
}
```

Входящий тип может быть и не `Date`.

Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "может быть и не Date"?

Comment: входящий тип параметра можно использовать любой. Т.е. в функцию можно передать 2 даты в любом виде, мне не принципиально, главное, хочу понять как высчитать разницу в днях

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете получить разницу между датами:

```
let dateDiff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2).day
```

Можно оформить в виде `extension` к `Date`:

```
extension Date {
    func days(to secondDate: Date, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Int {
        return calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: secondDate).day! // Здесь force unwrap, так как в компонентах указали .day и берем day
    }
}

let dateDiff = date1.days(to: date2)
```